# Count number of times an opp has been moved to different quarters

Tags: apex, opportunity, closedate, fiscal-periods

I want to be able to count the number of times an opportunity has been moved to different quarters.

So, every time the Close Date is edited and moved to a different quarter, I want an existing number field I have called "Quarters Pushed" to increase by 1.

I have created the following on Process Builder but the "Quarters Pushed" is not updating:-
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this easily with process builder. Just every time the close date changes such that it enters different Q increase the Quarters Pushed by 1.

Or you can go similarly with flow.

To track the close date quarter, you can use a Fiscal Period field, which holds this information.

---

E.g.:

1. create process on create/edit for the opp
2. new node where condition is formula `ISCHANGED([Opportunity].Fiscal)`
3. and action would be record update where `Quarters_Pushed__c =` formula `[Opportunity].Quarters_Pushed__c + 1`

Comment: This method relies on reps having to update the CloseDate field value. A lot of times reps forget to keep the CloseDate value updated.

Comment: 'So, every time the Close Date is edited and moved to a different quarter, I want an existing number field I have called "Quarters Pushed" to increase by 1.' i bet he is expecting exactly that.

Comment: Ah if that's the case, then yes Flows can take care of it easily

Comment: What criteria would you use for the flow? How do you know date falls in current quarter or next quarter?

Comment: Hi @Damecek, I have created the Process Builder but it's not working. When I move the Close Date to a different Quarter, it's not updating the Quarters Pushed field. Here is my Process Builder: – 

Object: Opportunity (when record is created or edited) 

[Opportunity].FiscalQuarter IS CHANGED True

Quarters Pushed FORMULA +1

Comment: add some screen shots to your question pls

Comment: @Damecek screen shots added

Comment: yes the formula to update needs to be like `[Opportunity].Quarters_Pushed__c + 1` not just `+1`